# App name doesn't change in launcher when using product flavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

Hi I am using product flavors in order to have a paid and free version of my app. I have managed to do whatever was needed. However the app name in laucher appears to be the same for both flavors. This is how I am doing it.

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.11"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App free"
    }
    pro {
        applicationId "com.my.app.pro"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App pro"
    }
}
```

Then in my manifest file I have the following line

```
android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Earlier I had a string app_name in my string resource file with the value "App free". I removed that string from the file and instead added strings to the product flavor block as above.

The problem is that in both the paid and free version the app name in the launcher shows as "App free" even though it should be "App pro" in the pro one.

The name appears right in the apps list in settings or at the time of install. It is only this name below the icon in the launcher that does not change.

I tried rebooting my phone but in vain. Can someone please help. I am using Nexus 5 Android 6. Thanks !!

Comment: Which launcher are you testing it on?

Comment: @KamranAhmed Default one

Comment: Have you tried to give each flavor a different application id?

Comment: @Christopher Yeah sorry, this isn't mentioned above, but both have a different application Id

Comment: Can you check the merged values.xml-file? You can find them there: app/build/intermediates/res/merged/<flavor>/<buildtype>/values/values.xml Is the string app_name different for each flavor?

Comment: @Christopher I have only one manifest file. As you can see in the edit, I have assigned values to app_name in the pro and free block inside productFlavor block. I don't set app_name anywhere else, not even in strings.xml. And then I use app_name in the label in the manifest as shown above. AM I doing something wrong?

Comment: @varunkr: You don't got me. Please look in the *merged* `values.xml`, as the definition in your `build.gradle` does not more than adding these string at compile time to your resources.

Comment: @Christopher Was able to fix this finally, although the app_name string was different in the values.xml file, but there was another string title_splash_activity which was set to App free, and it was picking it from there. I changed it and it worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the following command in your terminal:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" -d "package:com.your.package"
```

Replacing `com.your.package` with your application's package name. If it doesn't work you can try adding more specific details to it as mentioned [here in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED).

If this trick works out, you may send the same broadcast whenever the flavor of your app is changed, so that the launcher apps can know when it needs to refresh your application details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kamran, will check this.